# Stock Availbility not changing after cancel order Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory

Stock Availability not changing after cancel order, qty is updating but availability status not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Credits : **Marius**

There is a setting for that. It's

> System->Configuration->Inventory->Stock Options->Set Items Status

to be **In Stock** When Order is Cancelled.

Set that to ***Yes*** and ***clear the cache***.

Comment: i already did one but still not working.

Comment: qty is increasing but the stock availability is not changing, when order is cancelled I get the qty back but the stock availability status not going to out of stock to in stock

Comment: @vipin check this once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651622/magento-stock-status-out-of-stock-item-not-changing-even-the-quantity-is-greate

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to admin panel.
2. Go to system > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options > Set Items Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled.
3. Select to Yes.
4. Clear the cache.